# Stabilization Warning

Tags: vw, cel, jetta

I have a 2018 Jetta. I replaced the battery and when the car turned on, I had a stabilization warning. A diagnostic test was ran and a ton of codes started popping up.

What does the stabilization warning actually mean and can it be reset?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

This error is relatively common after a battery replacement. Drive it slowly for a few hundred feet and it should go away.